# How do I know if CAS instruction succeeded?

Tags: concurrency, concurrent-programming, compare-and-swap

A typical compare-and-swap instruction does not report whether it succeeded. Instead, it just returns the old value regardless. How can I very quickly determine if the CAS successfully updated the value?

```
CAS(location, compareValue, newValue):
  oldValue = *location
  if (oldValue == compareValue)
    *location = newValue;
  return oldValue ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial, you just compare the returned (old) value to the one CAS itself used for comparison.

```
 if (CAS(location, compareValue, newValue) == compareValue)
 {
   // CAS successfully wrote newValue to location
 }
 else
 {
   // CAS failed to write newValue to location
 }
```

That's how the x86's CMPXHG(8B/16B) instructions and MSVC++'s InterlockedCompareExchange*() functions that are built on top of them are used.